# Does Windows 8.1 Tablet support large tiles for a website?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a project in which it is required to add capabilities to a website by which a user can pin the site to the start screen of Windows 8.1.

This can be done by adding some "meta" tags in the head section of the HTML page.

I just have one question whether large tiles are supported on Windows 8.1 Tablet or not.

It is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx) that large tiles are not supported on Windows Phone. Does this mean that large tiles are supported on Windows 8.1 Tablet or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have live tiles for your website and they will work on windows phone. Scott Hanselman wrote a nice [blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeAWindows81PinnedLiveTileForYOURWebsiteInMinutes.aspx) on how this can be achieved.

Update:
Yes large tiles are supported on Windows 8.1 i.e. a tablet. You can see it when you pin [hanselmans](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) or my [blog](http://mallibone.com/) to the start menu.

Comment: Sorry I asked the wrong question.... Live tiles are supported for website and live tiles are of four types 1) Small 2) medium 3)Wide 4)Large. My confusion is whether Large tile is supported in Windows tablet or not. it is mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx that Large Live tile is not supported in Windows Phone, does that mean it will not support in Windows tablet also

Comment: @VikramSingh updated my answer according to your comment, HTH

Comment: Thank You mark... it would be great if you can share the link where it is mentioned that large tile is supported in Windows 8.1 tablet

Comment: @VikramSingh just visit Hanselmans blog it includes screenshots where you see that they are supported.